# 100% width on position absolute element

Tags: html, css, inheritance, absolute

I'm trying to make a `div` to have 100% width of its parent element (`body`). `body` has a horizontal scrollbar and the `div` only takes up the viewport width. To fix this I added

```
width: inherit;
```

to it. I expected it to work since `inherit`, according to the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit), means "taking the computed value of the property from its parent element". I tested it in a simpler model and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/EYgT9/.

However, when I apply the code to my actual project it doesn't work as expect. It doesn't even seem to follow the definition.

[image]
As you can see, the `div` has `inherit` as its `width`. But it's computed width is not the width of its parent `body`, instead it's some other value `302px`.

Now let's take a look `body`:
[image]
`body` clearly has a width of `470px`.

I couldn't figure out what's the reason behind this, making it not working as expected. The overall structure is the same as the fiddle, but result aren't the same.

What are the possible reason of this happening? Sorry that I couldn't post the relevant part of the code since I don't even where it's causing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the element with `position:absolute` is positioned in reference to `<html>` since `<body>` doesn't have a position to put it in reference to. Thus, it's inheriting its width from `html` as well.

To fix it, add `position:relative` to `body`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/EYgT9/2/)

Comment: I tried adding `relative` in, but sadly it's still not working properly. (If the `div` in relative to `html`, and `html` takes the width of the whole document, wouldn't it have the same effect?)

Answer (score 0):

Your body tag has position static and for the position absolute to work properly the parent element must have position set on either relative or absolute.
Just add position: relative or absolute; to the body tag.